# A way to open a new Finder window when double-clicking anywhere on the Desktop?

Tags: finder, desktop

Is there an existing utility app or pref pane to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with [Better Touch Tool](http://bettertouchtool.net/), as [Anonymous](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/25721/anonymous) mentioned. As a test, I set "Single Finger Tap Top Right" of the Trackpad to the pre-defined action "Open Finder." Presto, new Finder window.

[image: Better Touch Tool Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any utility that can do exactly that.

However, I would recommend using [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to achieve similar effect.